# Automap HttpWebRequests to a model

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https:...") as HttpWebRequest;
var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
var lines = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Now lines comes back as

> {"username":"me","gender":male}

and I want to auto map this to a model class, that I have set up like this,

```
public class Person
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
}
```

Any idea of how to go about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Newtonsoft.Json` for this task. Just add [Newtonsof.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) package to your project and then do:

```
var person = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Person>(lines);
```

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Please accept the answer after you tested and found this helpful. Thank you.